# Feynman Diagrams for Yukawa Theory

Tags: quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I am trying to draw the Feynman diagram for the following scattering amplitude (f a fermion)
$$
i\mathcal{M}(f\overline{f}\phi\phi\phi)
$$

Given the following interaction term in the Lagrangian:

$$
\mathcal{L}_I = -g\phi\psi\overline{\psi} 
$$

Now, I am trying to construct a feynman diagram from the rules of the theory, but I am having trouble recognising which diagrams are *not* allowed.

Which symmetries should I be respecting at each vertex?

Should I think of this as fermion/anti-fermion annihilation which produces two scalars, one of which then decays, producing another scalar?

Comment: Could you perhaps try to indicate more clearly what the initial and final particles are? Do you mean $i\mathcal M (f\bar f \to \phi\phi\phi)$?

Comment: I guess so, but actually I wouldn't mind knowing if any other initial/final states are even allowed by the theory. For example, I assume that $f\phi\longrightarrow\overline{f}\phi\phi$ isn't allowed, but not exactly certain on the reasons why.

Comment: when in doubt go back to wick contractions and commutation relations and derive the Feynman rules by your self!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $g\phi\bar{\psi}\psi$ is the only interaction term you will need at least 3 vertices to produce 3 external $\phi$-legs. Therefore, the amplitude at leading order in perturbation theory is going to be of the form
$$
\mathcal{M}\propto \bar{v}(p_1)\Delta_F(p_1-p_3)\Delta_F(p_1-p_3-p_4)u(p_2)+\ldots
$$
where $\Delta_F$ is the fermion propagator, and the $\ldots$ refers to the permutations of the three bosons momenta $p_3$, $p_4$ and $p_5$. 
It comes from the Feynmann diagrams where 3 boson legs attach to the internal fermion line in t-channel (corresponding i.e. to 2 fermionic propagators).